# How to show master view and root view in iOS swift in portrait orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

How do I can I make it possible to see the root view controller and the master at the same time in portrait mode?

example: the iOS Settings app.(On the iPad of course)

Comment: on iPhone in portrait mode the settings app isn't showing both views at the same time. Are you talking iPad?

Comment: Yes I am talking about the iPad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `preferredDisplayMode` on the splitViewController

```
splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible
```

Comment: This is deprecated in iOS 8

Comment: You are right about `shouldHideViewController`. Updated answer

Comment: Do I need to add the splitviewcontroller protocol to my split view controller since  I didn't make master detail application to start off

Comment: You shouldn't need to use UISplitViewControllerDelegate is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Due to limited space in portrait view it is recommended not to show both, master view controller as well as root view controller. I would suggest you to create your own customised masterview controller where you can use containers to show the controllers. You can also use tabbed view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do a dynamic selection in the main view, before layout calculations, setting a *minimum width* to activate a fixed split view:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    if UIScreen.main.bounds.width>600 {
        splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
    }else{
        splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = .automatic
    }
}
```